# Magento enterprise sending password in email not reset link

Tags: magento

i am using magento enterprise right now when user click on reset password fill email address our magento send password to user. but what i am trying to add reset link in email. i try to edit

```html
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/"_query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}">{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/"_query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}</a>

http://yoursite.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id={{var customer.id}}&token={{var customer.token}}

<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.token}}</a>
```

three of them not working customer token not coming in email i try with rp_tocken , token both has same problem token missing in email.

and when i click on link shows me 404..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while i was working on this functionality then i saw "  rp_token " not exist then what i did i create rp_token,ro_date attribute under customer then once user request for password reset then i just add values in these attributes then send email link.. here is full module :

http://www.sandeepsingh.us/product/magento-ajax-resetpassword-module/

download this module please read or install carefully if you are not able to run this left me know..